# Knockout is not binding to a span

Tags: knockout.js

Here's an basic example of doing binding with knockout but doesn't work and not sure why. This appear to follow every example I've seen.

```
var MyViewModel = {
    name: ko.observable("asdasdasd")
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r12v0jzj/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u4bpjnem/

Comment: @serhiyb This work in JSFiddle but when copy/paste into my project it doesn't. No console errors and jQuery and knockout libs are referenced, What do the script tags need to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyViewModel` is an object. So, `new MyViewModel()` is invalid:

So it should either be: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/r12v0jzj/1/))

```
var MyViewModel = {
    name: ko.observable("asdasdasd")
};

ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel);
```

OR

Use what is called [a constructor function](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword). This is similar to a `class` of C# or java. Whenever you call a `new` on this constructor function, it creates an object with `name` property. ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/r12v0jzj/2/))

```
var MyViewModel = function() {
    this.name = ko.observable("asdasdasd")
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

This creates an object exactly similar to the first example except for it's inner [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property.